# Checkers board - DP

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, dynamic-programming

Given a checkers board with 4 rows and `N` columns. each cell in the matrix has a value.
Given `2N` tokens that need to be placed on the board (each on a single cell) so the total  sum of all the values in the matrix's cells will be as big as possible (Maximum value).

The limit of placing the tokens is that two tokens can't be Horizontally or vertically adjacent to each other.

**You don't have to place all of the `2N` tokens.**

There are eight legal ways to place tokens in a column, So I define 8 arrays with the size of `N` when each one of them describes an option.

Anyways, using Dynamic Programming, I need to build a recursive equation for the problem.

I came up with:

```
A(i,j) = max { A(i,j) , A(i,j) + max { A(i-1,j-1) , ... , H(i-1,j-1) } } , B(i,j) = .... , H(i,j) = ...
```

When `A` is the first Array and `H` is the 8th array.

Now, I don't think that my recursive equation is good. And even if it is, I have no idea how to add the conditions (two tokens can't be horizontally or vertically adjacent to each other) to the recursive equation.

Can anyone try to help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is effectively the same as unkulunkulu's, although independently derived.  I include it here because it may be notationally better or slightly simpler to handle with arrays.

In following, let `p` or `q` in {0..7} be indexes of one of the eight configurations, and let `k` be a column index.  Let `V(k,p)` be the value of configuration `p` in column `k`.  Let `W(k,p)` be the value of the best configuration of columns `0..k` that ends with configuration `p` in column `k`.  Let `φ(p,q)` be 1 if configurations `p,q` are allowed adjacent, else 0.  (`φ` is equivalent to unkulunkulu's graph incidence matrix.) Symbol ∞ represents a number larger than the sum of the matrix's positive cell values.

Then W(k+1,p) = V(k+1,p) + max<sub>q∈{0..7}</sub>(W(k,q)·φ(p,q) + ∞·(φ(p,q)-1))
when k≥0, and W(0,p)=V(0,p).

Comment: An interesting alternative answer would be the one to solve the generalized problem (for any `4` so to speak :D)

Answer (score 2):

Right, you have 8 possible ways to place tokens in a column:

```
A B C D E F G H
e *       *   *
m   *       *
p     *   *
t       *   * *
y
```

Now, you can only have particular columns following other columns. For example:

1. `A` can be a neighbor to any column,
2. Only `A` can be a neighbor to itself,
3. `B` can be a neighbor to `C` and `G`, but cannot be a neighbor to another `B` or `F` or `H`,
4. `H` can only be a neighbor to `A`, `C` or `D`, etc.

One thing to note is that `A` can be useful if the given column is neighbor to both `F` and `G`.

So we have a (undirected) graph:

```
  A B C D E F G H
A + + + + + + + +
B + - + + + - + -
C + + - + + + - +
D + + + - + - + +
E + + + + - + - -
F + - + + + - + -
G + + - + - + - -
H + - + + - - - -
```

Above is the incidence matrix.

After that, we define `A(i)` to be the maximum possible sum we can get from first `i` columns if the `i th` column ended in a type `A` token placement. The same for `B`, `C`, ..., `H`.

Then you have a recursive formula:

```
X(i+1) = {max Y(i) where X and Y can be neighboring columns} + 
         {sum of the cells in the i+1 column for placement X}
```

here `X` runs through all the possible placements `A`, `B`, `C`, ..., `H`.

The initial values are `A(0) = 0, B(0) = 0, ..., H(0) = 0`.

The final answer is `max{ A(N), B(N), C(N), D(N), ..., H(N) }`.

*Note:*

The above is the solution, or the idea, the implementation can be different. For example, you can hardcode everything (assuming `Board[i][j]` is the value placed on the board, indices start from `0`):

```
F(i+1) = max{ A(i), C(i), E(i), G(i) } +  // This is from the matrix above
         Board[0][i+1] + Board[2][i+1]    // This is from the definition of F type column
```

And similar for every letter. You don't have to have the incidence matrix as a real entity in the program, just have it in mind while constructing the expressions.